# Actually snapping to pixel grid

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pixel

Does anyone know if there's a way to have Illustrator CC (2014) constrain control points to the pixel grid? I understand that "Align to pixel grid" makes it so that a shape will try to match the pixel grid, but the actual control points don't line up to said grid... The image I've attached illustrates my problem.

[image: While the shape constrains to the pixel grid, the control points don't]

Comment: Hi user34563, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Do you have pixel preview on? Use preview bounds on in the prefs? Have you tried simply nudging the artwork to make the anchors snap tot he pixel grid?

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of the decimal points for both X and Y axis in the toolbar? If not give it a try...
Same for width and height... Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem and you were clearly displayed the pixel view is on so don't worry about that and don't get a confuse. Try to change the options Snap to pixel, Snap to Point and Align to Pixel grid.

My answer may help you :)

Answer (score 0):

When the preview does not line up to the actual path there are a couple things which may be occurring.

If Pixel Preview is not on, turn it on `View > Pixel Preview`.

If things are set to align to the pixel grid. Nudge the object. Just select it and hit the up arrow, then the down arrow.

Turn on `View > Snap to Pixel`